# email dead after updating dns records

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, dns-zone, email-bounces

I was integrating with woodpecker.co which required me to set up a sub-domain on mailgun before I could integrate my email.

I set up the DNS as requested and here is the result. Its from an VM running on Azure Portal

[image: DNS settings]

It appeared to work as you can see all the correct marks showed when I clicked the button to check DNS settings.

[image: mailgun DNS check]

I can send emails through the woodpecker service from my email now and also via outlook however when someone sends me an email I get the following error:

The response from the remote server was:
550 5.1.0 Recipient rejected:

Final-Recipient: rfc822; xxx@xxx.net
Action: failed
Status: 5.1.0
Remote-MTA: dns; mxb.mailgun.org. (34.232.219.201, the server for the domain xxx.net.)
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 5.1.0 Recipient rejected:

I did not touch any other mailgun or server settings. I have my own mail server and I have not touched any settings on this, the only thing I changed was the DNS settings. Should I just wait 24-48 hours, is it a propagating issue or did I break something with the new DNS settings? Maybe its because I created a new subdomain and I need to update something on my mail server. I don't really want to change anything on the mail server settings as a lot of things touch it and it could break them (well I guess its already broken but don't want to make it worse.)

Any ideas?

Comment: If you have your own mail server, why are you sending all your incoming mail to mailgun?

Comment: @MichaelHampton to be fair, only about 2/3 of the mail will be going to mailgun...

Comment: Yep that was it, I removed the mx records for mxa and mxb and it worked. Might be obvious if I knew what mx records were for but I was just blindly changing records based on an article, feel free to add solution and I will select it as the answer.

Comment: What mx records did you instead that worked? You said you removed the two mx records so I'm assuming you replaced them with two other MX records?